# Sorting sap ui5 table before displaying using odata model

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, sapui5

I have a doubt on sapui5 table sorting, I am using the service url to get the data into a tree table and binding the resulted data which i got from the service url.

My question is defaultly it is sorted on the other field, but i want to sort on the base of date field, how could i sort the table before displaying in the table columns using ui.commons controls in xml views

Comment: It would help if you indicate which table you are using, the sap.m.Table or sap.ui.Table. Their APIs are different.

Comment: he said tree table, what else Information do you need? can't you sort in the webservice method / backend where you get data from? or is it during runtime?

Comment: Hello jpenninkhof, as i am using sap.ui.table.. i knew while using sap.m. table we can directly pass sorter field in the items..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use [`sortProperty`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.table.Column.html#getSortProperty) of [`sap.ui.table.Column`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.table.Column.html#getSortProperty)

> `sortProperty` Specifies the binding property on which the column will sort.

For example, if you want to sort table based on `Name` property.

```
<t:columns>
    <t:Column sortProperty="Name" sorted="true" >
        <t:label>
            <Text text="Name" />
        </t:label>
        <t:template>
            <Text text="{Name}"></Text>
        </t:template>
    </t:Column>
</t:columns>
```